# Pass data to FormBuilder from other component

Tags: angular, angular2-formbuilder

i have problem with populating Formbuilder from other component.

component1: Here is component that calls component that needs to display data:

```
    import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
    import { component2 } from '../component2.component';

    export class component1 implements OnInit {        
        constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private cocf: component2)

          showModal(id: number) {
            const modalRef = this.modalService.open(component2);
            this.cocf.fillData(id);
          }
}
```

component2: And here is component that needs to display data:

```
        import { DataService } from '../../../services/data.service';
        import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal, NgbModule, NgbDateParserFormatter } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
        import { Validators, FormGroup, FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

        export class component2 implements OnInit {        
        showData: FormGroup;

        constructor( private modalService: NgbModal, public _fb: FormBuilder)

        ngOnInit(){
        this.showData = this._fb.group({
         here are default values
        })
        }

    fillData(id){
        this.DataService.getDataById(id)
          .subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data
            console.log(this.data);
              this.showData.pathValue({
               here are updated values of initial data
           })
          });
    }
}
```

Data in console.log() is OK. Error i am getting:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'patchValue' of undefined
```

If i am calling function fillData inside component2 it works correctly. How can i fix this problem? Is it because of references or must i initialize new formgroup? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this:
`const modalRef = this.modalService.open(component2);`

Should be this:

`const modalRef = this.modalService.open(this.cocf);`

Also, did you try moving your formBuilder in your fillData method like so:

```
fillData(id){
    this.showData = this._fb.group({
       here are default values
    });

    this.DataService.getDataById(id)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data
        console.log(this.data);
          this.showData.pathValue({
           here are updated values of initial data
       })
  });
```

Comment: Did both if i change to: const modalRef = this.modalService.open(this.cocf); i get error. If i add initial values to fillData error is gone but data doesnt fill formBuilder. Any other idea?

Comment: ERROR Error: No component factory found for [object Object]. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?  I added component2 in in entryComponents in app.module.